# Onclick event working and not working on the same code

Tags: javascript, html, yui-pure-css

I have this page where I have a menu (using Pure) and I have some links taht when clicked run a javascript to change a picture on the page. For some reason, when the code is inside the Pure menu, it does not run. When it is outside the menu it runs without a problem.

Any ideas why this is happening or any tips for a more elegant solution?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dashboard</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css">

<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.17.2/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>

<script>
YUI({
    classNamePrefix: 'pure'
}).use('gallery-sm-menu', function (Y) {

    var horizontalMenu = new Y.Menu({
        container         : '#demo-horizontal-menu',
        sourceNode        : '#std-menu-items',
        orientation       : 'horizontal',
        hideOnOutsideClick: false,
        hideOnClick       : false
    });

    horizontalMenu.render();
    horizontalMenu.show();

});
</script>

<script>
function changeIt(imageName,objName)
{
var obj = document.getElementById(objName);

var imgTag = "<img src='"+imageName+"' border='0' />";

obj.innerHTML = imgTag;

return; 
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="demo-horizontal-menu">
<a href="#" class="pure-menu-heading">Site Title</a>
    <ul id="std-menu-items">

        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu (Not Working)</a>
            <ul>

                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeIt('1.jpg','image-dash');">Dashboard 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeIt('2.jpg','image-dash');">Dashboard 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeIt('3.jpg','image-dash');">Dashboard 3</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="image-dash">
<img src="1.jpg" border="0">
</div>

<p>These links here will work for some reason..</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="changeIt('1.jpg','image-dash');">Dashboard 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="changeIt('2.jpg','image-dash');">Dashboard 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" onclick="changeIt('3.jpg','image-dash');">Dashboard 3</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't get this `YUI({` part. You have an IIFE and outside you're written `YUI`.  Do you have any error in console..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is related to how the YUI Menu widget is created. If you take a look at the rendered code, you can see that your anchor tags don't have the `onclick` attribute anymore:

**original syntax (has onclick)**

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="changeIt('1.jpg','image-dash');">Dashboard 1</a></li>
```

**rendered yui menu item (doesn't have onclick)**

```
<li id="menuItem-yui_3_17_2_1_1402336941070_76" class="pure-menu-item" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="yui_3_17_2_1_1402336941070_87" role="menuitem">
    <a href="#" class="pure-menu-label" data-item-id="menuItem-yui_3_17_2_1_1402336941070_76" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1402336941070_87">Dashboard 1</a>
</li>
```

That being said, you have some choices:

- dive into the YUI API to find a way to add attributes to your menu items (recommended)
- use the href to execute your javascript function:

  `<a href="javascript:changeIt('1.jpg','image-dash');">Dashboard 1</a></li>`